# jQuery code works in IE9 but fails in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I have written a jQuery code that works in IE9 but fails in FireFox.

The code is using jQuery UI to create a jQuery dialog with a set of items generated by a PHP page. the user will make a selection and the selected item should be added to a div container using a JS function.

Below is my code:

```
$(function() {
        $("#add-item-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 800,
                modal: true,

            close: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" )
                    return false;
            }

        });
        $("#add-item")
            .button()
            .click(function() {
            $( "#add-item-dialog" ).load('add_item.php').dialog('open');
            });


        });
        function addItem(message){
            alert(message);
            $('#item_list').append(message + '<br>');
            $("#add-item-dialog").dialog("close")
                    return false;
        }
```

The button for the function addItem is dynamically created with PHP as follows:

```
<input type="button" name="Add Item" value="'.$item_name.'" onClick="addItem(this.value)">
```

The expected output is an alert with the item name... then the item name is appended to the `item_list` div tag.

IE9 will append the text to the div, however, FireFox will only display the alert then do nothing.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Code works in IE but fails in FireFox? Parallel universe?

Comment: Is there an error message in the console? What is `#item_list` what is `message`? Details = better answers.

Comment: @Narek Hahahahaha! Yeah, I had to read the title twice because I didn't believe it the first time I read it.

Comment: Is there a duplicate another element with id item_list? IDs should be unique.

Comment: @span http://jsfiddle.net/A8xtV/

Comment: Thanks @Jaitsu, I get the feeling it's missing some of the HTML so it's a bit hard to see where the other scripts are called and how.

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdchaara/HaRq8/

Comment: I get this in the console: [16:04:24.746] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. @ http://localhost/mdp/scripts/jquery/jq19.js:6208

Comment: @ Narek  and  howderek: I find it very strange that I get the result in IE but not in firefox. It is ALWAYS the other way around, hence the question.

Comment: @span: right now there is one scripts that is being called.

Comment: Witch jQuery version you are using?

Comment: What does the code in the dynamically loaded php look like? Probably the most important piece is missing. How is `addItem(message)` triggered?

Comment: @epascarello: the code generates multiple items from an array. I will add it to the question.

Comment: @MDChaara it's a FireFox internal error. I'm checking now for some answers.

Comment: have you checked out this link: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-append-not-working-in-firefox
seem like Firefox wants your html to pitch-perfect.

Comment: @MDChaara here you go - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12072 ,you could just go into your plugin and change the func()

Comment: Showing the php code does not really help. What does `<input type="button" name="Add Item" value="'.$item_name.'" onClick="addItem(this.value)">` actually look like?

Comment: @epascarello problem isn't with his code, problem is within jquery plugins and firefox internal functions.

Comment: once generated, it would be <input type="button" name="Add Item" value="item_a" onClick="addItem(this.value)"> What I would need to be added to the div tag is item_a

Comment: @skmasq, A warning that something is deprecated does not mean it stops working.

Comment: @epascarello As you can see OP is in fact trying to fetch attribute from element, and console drops error about `getAttributeNode()` being used which is deprecated, so if it's deprecated it shouldn't work when called, that's why OP should try to rewrite code so it uses `getAttribute()` instead.

Comment: @skmasq: Actually uninstalling firebug did allow the item to be added. to the div.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to actually run. http://jsfiddle.net/VZhYg/ and it works without any problem on FF for me. There is something else going on. And @skmasq deprecation does not mean they removed the support, it means they are going to in a future release and this is a warning.

Comment: @epascarello Yes I understand, but it seem I was right before, that firebug is indeed in fault here.

Comment: @skmasq: Firebug removal did the trick, and I updated my code with the code you have posted. All works well. Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uninstall fire bug, it seems to be the problem while doing some research.

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
function addItem(message){
            var tmp_msg = message;
            alert(message);
            $('#item_list').append(tmp_msg + '<br>');
            $("#add-item-dialog").dialog("close")
                    return false;
        }
```

Maybe it's problem with `.append()` where it calls `this.value` instead of just getting the actual value.

As you wrote earlier `alert()` does work, so it's the `.append()` function that doesn't work, I think you need to get actual value from `this.value` and then pass it to `.append()` .

Let me know, how it goes.

Comment: Firebug removal did the trick, and I updated my code with the code you have posted. All works well. Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have installed firebug again and tested the code. It works now.I thought someone might find this of use.

Comment: @MDChaara Yeah, I think it's the problem with reference where `jQuery.append()` takes `this.value`, so you need to get the value from it and then provide it to function.